# How to trigger nextjs default 500 error page

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am unable to trigger the Next.js's 500 error page. Most resources talks about making a custom error page but the Next.js doc briefly mentions their default 500 error page. I would like to trigger this default page when the API responds with a 500 status.

Given an API response of 500 Next.js should display a 500 error page. So far it returns to the page where the request was made.

```
return res.status(500).end();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to throw a 500 error from getStaticProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71119300/how-to-throw-a-500-error-from-getstaticprops)

Comment: 500 renders if I directly throw but this solution doesn't fully answer my question. `getStaticProps` & `getServerSideProps` doesn't run on form submission. Responding with an 500 or manually throwing doesn't trigger the 500 page.

Comment: You can manually render the error page on the client-side, see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#reusing-the-built-in-error-page.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you. Do you know why response status of 500 doesn't trigger the error page though? The solution right now seems to be a manual redirect instead of a 500 response or redirect after receiving a 500 response.

Comment: _"why response status of 500 doesn't trigger the error page"_ - not sure I follow. Also, note that showing the 500 error page only happens in production mode (`npm run build && npm start`).

Comment: My page makes API request and some would respond with status of 500, 404, 200, etc. In cases where the response is 500 the error page does not render. I've been building and testing the app.

Comment: You would need to handle those API responses yourself to trigger the 500 error page.

Comment: Hi @Dan, any update on this? I'm in the same position right now. I cannot find any documentation about how to trigger the default 500 next js page when I set the res.statusCode to 500.

Comment: @IonutEnache I haven't revisit this yet. But I did notice a funny issue with 404 page when redirecting unauthorized users will result in infinite loops. Creating a custom 404 page resolves this error. I am planning to just create a custom 500 error page as well.

Comment: In version 13 and app folder also doesnt work, even if you throw new Error('') nothing happens. :|

Answer (score 9):

The only solution I found is to throw an unhandled error from `getServerSideProps`:

```
res.statusCode = 500;
throw new Error('Internal Server Error');
```

I saw that NextJs handle this as a 500 status code, but only on the production/staging environment. `npm run dev` will not work, and you will not be able to see the default 500 page.

I needed to throw a 500 status code to prevent Google from deindexing my page because the page content suffered significant changes, and the products from this page were not available anymore.

Answer (score 5):

After defining the custom 500 page at `pages/500.ts` as mentioned in the [official doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#500-page), I'm able to access this page at the url path `/500`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I was able to trigger this, using `npm run build` and `npm run start`

(I put this random error trigger in my index page)

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  function getRandomInt(max: number): number {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }
  if (getRandomInt(10) === 5) {
    throw new Error('Internal Server Error');
  }

  return {
    props: {
    },
  }
}
```